# Google Container Registry and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, kubernetes, google-container-registry

I have been trying to setup Jenkins to utilize Kubernetes as in the tutorials.  I have everything working really well, but I have been trying to add some custom images using the Kubernetes Jenkins plugin.  It seems that any public images work just fine, but when I create an image and put it in my private Container Registry, the Jenkins slave fails miserably.

I wanted to find out how best to utilize the images in my Container Registry within Jenkins.  I found this tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-container-engine#customizing_the_docker_image).  When I tried those steps by building the jenkins-slave image and pushing it to my repo, it did not work.  Every time it complains the slave is offline and is unable to be reached.

Comment: Could you paste the exact error?

Comment: There isn't really an error per say.  Jenkins says the build agent is "offline", saying "This agent is offline because Jenkins failed to launch the agent process on it. ".  There is no log as the Jenkins server can't connect to the agent.  I have to imagine it has something to do with not being able to find the proper image/have access to the private Google Cloud Registry.

Comment: Is the image stored on the same project that you use to deploy to container engine? If not, please try pushing the image to that project

Comment: Yes, the image is in the same project, confirmed via the Google Cloud Console.  I found I didn't have a service account setup, but after doing so, I still have the same issue. I have to imagine it has some authentication issue, but can't figure out what I missed

Comment: I have done a bit more digging and am still stumped.  I was able to deploy my custom image manually in Kubernetes by creating a pod.  I believe this means the cluster is configured correctly.  

I pushed a copy of gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/jenkins-k8s-slave to my Google Cloud Container Registry and tried to reference it from my Jenkins master.  It was still unsuccessful.  I believe this rules out the image being bad since it's a duplicate of a known good image.  

I am still stump as to what the problem is referencing customer Jenkins build agents in my Google Docker registry...

Answer (score 1):

Never tried google container registry but from what I understand is that you can just use the complete repo+image name. Something like:
gcr.io/my_project/image:tag

Make sure your images/repo are under the same service account as your kubernetes and jenkins on google cloud!

Comment: I was able to manually create a pod with my custom image via kubectl.  The service account matches the cluster in which kubernetes/Jenkins lives.

Answer (score 1):

When a container build agent (old term was `slave`) shows as *Offline* within Jenkins, this usually means there was an error in the Jenkinsfile if using Pipeline, or there was a problem pulling the agent image container.

If you're using the Kubernetes Plugin, you'll see the error on the Kubernetes pod, and in the build logs in newer versions of the plugin. For docker plugin containers, the error may not be visible in the build log, but would be in the docker logs.

This is usually a problem of authentication or access for pulling the image from the registry.

If you're using the **[Jenkins Kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/)**, the Pod YAML or Pod Template must contain the [`imagePullSecrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) for the Container Registry from which you wish to pull the container image from.

*Jenkins Scripted Pipeline:*

```
node {
  podTemplate(cloud: 'kubernetes', containers: [
    containerTemplate(
      name: 'mine',
      image: 'my-image:v1.2',
      ttyEnabled: true,
    ),
  ], 
  imagePullSecrets: [ 'my-credentials-id' ]) {
    sh 'run command'
  }
}
```

*Jenkins Declarative Pipeline:*

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      cloud 'kubernetes'
      defaultContainer 'mine'
      yaml '''
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    build: my-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mine
      image: my-image:v1.2
      command:
        - cat
      tty: true
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: my-image-pull-cred
    '''
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Run Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn -version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using the **[Docker plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/)**, you'll need to define the docker agent `withRegistry` which allows you to pass a Jenkins credential for the registry from which you wish to pull the container image from.

*Jenkins Scripted Pipeline:*

```
node {
  docker.withRegistry('https://my-registry.gcr.io', 'my-credentials-id') {
    docker.image('my-image:v1.2').inside {
      sh 'run command'
    }
  }
}
```

*Jenkins Declarative Pipeline:*

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'my-image:v1.0'
      registryUrl 'https://my-registry.gcr.io'
      registryCredentialsId 'my-credentials-id'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'run command'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really good info. For those using GCR, the credentials need to be prepended: ```gcr:credentials-id```.